# How can power sharing make a democracy more powerful?

Tags: power-sharing

In a democracy, power can be shared among different organs of the government and at different levels. There are both prudential and moral reasons for power sharing. However it could be argued that the sharing of power=dividing the power=weakening the country. How can power sharing make a country more powerful?

Comment: Aren't all democracies sharing power? Like in Parliament or with government ministers? Without power sharing they wouldn't be democracies or do I misunderstand it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- It assures policies which are carried by a broad consensus of the population. Such a consensus increases democratic engagement, and democracies like to believe that they are structurally stronger than autocracies. That isn't proven, but it is somewhat plausible.
- It reduces the likelihood of sudden, major changes in policy, especially back and forth as a narrow majority changes. Such changes are bad for social cohesion and the economy, hence bad for the country.
- It assures a smoother transition of power at the retirement or death of a powerful individual.

Comment: +1 Having people who will challenge your policies makes you ensure you have thought them through properly and have considered all the objections. A leader surrounded by a bunch of "yes men" will make poorer decisions than one where his decisions are queried and probed.

Comment: I'm not sure how this answer got accepted. Literally every point also applies in a monarchy. For example, look at the Chinese monarchs (e.g. Qing dynasty) that had huge bureaucracies. They were structurally stable, they didn't change laws often, and they had smooth power transitions (after all, heirs were chosen decades in advance).